# To-Do-List Add-new-item button doesn't add anything

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am still new to React and I have so much trouble finding out where is the problem, I know it must be something with function call, also tried to debug but didn't work, don't know any other way(tools) how to find out where is the problem.

**App.tsx**

```
const App = () => {

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState<string[]>(["Task1", "Task2"]);

  const addTask = (task : string) => {
    setTasks([...tasks, task]);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <SubmissionBox tasks={tasks} addTask={addTask}/>
      <Tasks tasks={tasks}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**SubmissionBox.tsx**

```
interface ISubmissionProps {
  tasks : string[];
  addTask : (task : string) => void;
}

const SubmissionBox = (props : ISubmissionProps) => {
    const [task, setTask] = useState("");
    const onTaskChange = (e : any) : void => {
        setTask(e.target.value);
    }
    return (
        <>
        <InputGroup>
            <Input placeholder="Add new task..." value={task} onChange={onTaskChange}/>
            <Button color="success" type="submit" onSubmit={() => props.addTask(task)}>Submit</Button>
        </InputGroup>
        </>
    );
}

export default SubmissionBox;
```

**Tasks.tsx**

```
const Tasks = ({tasks} : {tasks:string[]}) => {

  return (
    <>
      <ListGroup>
        {tasks.map((item: any, i: any) => (
          <ListGroupItem className="d-flex justify-content-between" key={i}>{item}<Button color="danger">Remove</Button></ListGroupItem>
        ))}
      </ListGroup>
    </>
  );
};

export default Tasks;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On button you need to change prop `onSubmit` to `onClick`

```
<Button color="success" type="button" onClick={() => props.addTask(task)}>Submit</Button>
```

Comment: That way I get quite long error ending with "...Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: FormEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void) | undefined'.  TS2769"

Comment: Oh My Goooood..Thanks, I don't know why I ended up writing OnSubmit, I spent last 30 minutes trying to figure out what's wrong. Thanks so much

Comment: you need to change props `onSubmit` to `onClick` in button